# Adding multiple ndarry using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vector

I am quite new to python numpy.

If i do have a list of numpy vectors. What is the best way to ensure computation is fast.

I am currently doing this which i find it to be too slow.

```
vec = sum(list of numpy vectors) # 4 vectors of 500 dimensions each
```

It does take up quite a noticeable amount of time using sum.

Comment: Your description of the problem is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying to do (but with much larger arrays)?

```
In [193]: sum([np.ones((2,3)),np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)])
Out[193]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.]])
```

`500 dimensions each` is an unclear description.  Do you mean an array with shape `(500,)` or with `ndim==500`?  If the latter, just how many elements total are there.

The fact that it is a list of 4 of these arrays shouldn't be a big deal.  What's the time for `array1 + array2`?

If the arrays just have 500 elements each, the sum time is trivial:

```
In [195]: timeit sum([np.arange(500),np.arange(500),np.arange(500),np.arange(500)]) 
10000 loops, best of 3: 20.9 µs per loop
```

on the other hand a sum of arrays with many small dimensions is slower simply because such an array is much larger

```
In [204]: x=np.ones((3,)*10)

In [205]: timeit z=sum([x,x,x,x])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.6 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this is already the fastest variant. It is pure `numpy` and as such computed within `C`-code.

Alternatives could be to compute the sums of each vector individually and then sum the values of the list or to stack all vectors and then sum up. But both are slower:

```
import numpy as np
import time

n = 10000

start = time.time()
for i in range(n): 
    lst = np.hstack([np.random.random(500) for i in range(4)])
    x = np.sum(lst)
print("stack then np.sum: ", time.time()- start)

start = time.time()
for i in range(n): 
    lst = [np.sum(np.random.random(500)) for i in range(4)]
    x = np.sum(lst)
print("sum up individually: ", time.time()- start)


start = time.time()
for i in range(n):
    lst = [np.random.random(500) for i in range(4)]
    x = np.sum(lst)
print("np.sum on list of vectors:", time.time()- start)
```

output:

> stack then np.sum:  0.35804247856140137
>
> sum up individually:  0.400468111038208
>
> np.sum on list of vectors: 0.3427283763885498